# Regular expression that checks for 2 specific words, both of them have to be found

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that checks whether a string contains both of the specific words. e.g. whether the string contains rooster AND hen.

More in detail:

These shouldn't be matches:
1. "rooster"
2. "hen"
3. "heroostern"

These should be matches:
1. "rooster hen"
2. "rooster cock hen"
3. "hen rooster"
4. "roosterhen"
5. "henrooster"
6. "henchmen garoostern"

Comment: There must be more behind what you describe. Looking for two explicit parts is probably step three in any tutorial on regexes. So please give more detail. What did you try? Why did it fail? What are examples of input? Which should be matches, and which should not. In the too simple form described, your question is unclear and cannot be answered. Or you have really not spent the least bit of effort. Which makes the question just seriously downvotable. But I assume (in your favor) that you just phrased not clearly enough.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: What about "hen rooster", "roosterhen", "henrooster", "henchmen garoostern" ?

Comment: `\brooster\b.*\bhen\b`

Comment: Giving more details on what you want is not enough. You are also expected to give the impression that you did some trying and experimenting yourself. Please refrain from anythign on the tune of "I did a lot of work.", "I read many things on the internet." Show the result of your work and explain in which way it did not work.

Comment: Try `\brooster.*hen\b|\bhen.*rooster\b` https://regex101.com/r/35SMNm/1

Comment: @iBug Your proposal does not match "hen rooster". Waiting for the unclear question to become clear is recommended.

Comment: OK, don't help me, Jesus Christ. I didn't do a lot of work. That's why I'm asking the question. I don't know regex, that's why I'm asking. I googled for a few minutes and couldn't find the results. As it seems I'll have to learn regex for this simple task.

Comment: @Yunnosch That's why I post it as a comment.

Comment: You did not do a lot of work and ask an (initially) unclear question here, expecting others to do the work mostly in the shape of guessing. Yes, that was obvious from start. So what do you expect? A free code writing service? People spending their free time for things you could not be bothered to do?

Comment: @Yunnosch he edited his question. Now it matches.

Comment: Question is clear now, true. Still, no visible own effort.

Comment: @Yunnosch Agreed!

Comment: Yes, I expected that and got it. Nobody's forcing anyone to comment or answer, you can also report this question or do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @S.Kablar.

Comment: I asked a simple question for people who know regex. And yes, I expected to get an answer. Yes, it was unclear initially and that's my bad, but is it that bad to ask somebody to do something on the web? Is this the first time you've come across this? I watched introduction videos about regex but it wasn't enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**: `\brooster[n0-9]?.*hen[0-9]?\b|\bhen[0-9]?.*rooster[n0-9]?\b`

**Details**:

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary
- `|` or
- `.` matches any character
- `*` Matches between zero and unlimited times
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list `n` or number `0-9`
- `?` Matches between zero and one times

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/35SMNm/3)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't match "henchmen garoostern" but that's good enough for me for now. Extra thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @musicinmusic roostern or rooster?

Comment: "roostern". I'm trying to create a blacklist using regex, "hen1 rooster1" would be one way to get around the blacklist.

Comment: @musicinmusic Updated!